# Error 1006 : Swapdepths is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3, depth

I'm having some trouble with swapDepths function. I'm programming a drag/drop system. I created a empty MovieClip (depthSwaper), with the highest depth, and every time I drag one of my objects, I swap its depths with depthSwaper, so my object is always on the highest depth.

Problem, I get this error : "Error #1006 : swapDepths is not a function".

Here's my script :

```
public function monDown(e:MouseEvent) {
            e.currentTarget.icone.swapDepths(depthSwaper);
            e.currentTarget.startDrag();
        } //monDown

        public function monUp(e:MouseEvent) {

            e.currentTarget.icone.swapDepths(depthSwaper);
            e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
            if(e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(slotTete) && (e.currentTarget.type == "arme")) {
                e.currentTarget.x = slotTete.x;
                e.currentTarget.y = slotTete.y;
            } else if(e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(slotTorse) && (e.currentTarget.type == "torse")) {
                e.currentTarget.x = slotTorse.x;
                e.currentTarget.y = slotTorse.y;
            } else {
                annulerDrag(e.currentTarget);
            }

        } //monUp
```

currentTarget.icone is the MovieClip I'm moving. I tried to use swapdepth with just a number, like this : e.currentTarget.icone.swapDepths(10);
but i'm getting the same error.

Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no swapDepths function is AS3.  You can do what you need with `swapChildren()`. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildren%28%29

Basically you call it on the container of your two clips, and it swaps their depths:

```
myContainer.swapChildren(child1,child2);
```

or, in context (hopefully):

```
e.currentTarget.swapChildren(icone,depthSwaper);
```

Answer (score 1):

swapDepths is AS2 , you need to use one of AS3's  new tricks

Well explained here: http://www.as3dtk.com/?p=493